# Parse XML in python with multiple childs

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
        <OCR_ERRORS_TABLE>
                <FIGURE>
                        <ELEMENT>
                                <REF>0</REF>
                                <MISREAD_CHARS>O</MISREAD_CHARS>
                        </ELEMENT>
                        <ELEMENT>
                                <REF>1</REF>
                                <MISREAD_CHARS>rilLM</MISREAD_CHARS>
                        </ELEMENT>
                        <ELEMENT>
                                <REF>6</REF>
                                <MISREAD_CHARS>G</MISREAD_CHARS>
                        </ELEMENT>
                </FIGURE>
                <LETTER>
                        <ELEMENT>
                                <REF>O</REF>
                                <MISREAD_CHARS>0</MISREAD_CHARS>
                        </ELEMENT>
                </LETTER>
        </OCR_ERRORS_TABLE>
</ROOT>
```

In different case, I have to get the FIGURE elements or the LETTER. My problem is that I don't know how to iterate on the elements and get the REF and MISREAD_CHARS into var.

For now here is my python code, usin ElementTree lib :

```
configPath = 'config/ocr_errors.xml'
root = ET.parse(configPath).getroot()

if letterToFigure:
    for child in root.find('.//FIGURE//ELEMENT'):
        print child.get('REF')
```

But the last print gave me "None".

Maybe it could help, but here is a PHP version of what I want, that working :

```
$ocrErrorsTbl=simplexml_load_file($this->_working_directory_path."/config/ocr_errors.xml");
    if($letterToFigure)
        foreach($ocrErrorsTbl->OCR_ERRORS_TABLE->FIGURE->ELEMENT as $ele)
            $OCRERRTBL[(string)$ele->REF]=(string)$ele->MISREAD_CHARS;
    else
        foreach($ocrErrorsTbl->OCR_ERRORS_TABLE->LETTER->ELEMENT as $ele)
            $OCRERRTBL[(string)$ele->REF]=(string)$ele->MISREAD_CHARS;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` returns an attribute not child. You could do something like this:

```
result = {}
if letterToFigure:
    for child in root.findall('.//FIGURE/ELEMENT'):
        ref, misread = list(child)
        result[ref.text] = misread.text

print result
```

Returns:

```
{'1': 'rilLM', '0': 'O', '6': 'G'}
```